# Adicionar registos à MSFlexGrid através de textbox em VBA

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6

Como consigo adicionar registos à MSFlexGrid através de uma textbox em VBA?
Encontrei uma forma de o fazer ( http://www.macoratti.net/gridedit.htm ) mas para vb6, usando o screen.twipsperpixelx que não existe em vba... Alguem com uma solução? Muito obrigado.

Comment: Eu não tenho 100% de certeza, mas acho que esse componente não é utilizável no VBA. Você conseguiu ao menos instanciar um num formulário? Aliás, se o uso intencionado for no Excel, isso não faz sentido algum (afinal o Excel já tem a sua própria estrutura tabular...).

Comment: Eu consegui instanciar, não é excel.